# Connecting QGIS to Google spreadsheets

Tags: qgis, google-sheets

Is there a way to connect directly form QGIS to a Google spreadsheet?

The purpose for pulling data from a Google spreadsheet is diverse. This could be to pull coordinate values from a questionnaire or content for atlas making.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a way to connect the sheet via the [Google sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/) as Cezar mentioned. Instructions can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python). After connecting to the API, you have to create a python (pyQGIS) script that pulls from the google sheet and creates points for the layer, a tutorial can be found [here](https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis101-creating-editing-a-new-vector-layer/). I created an example (with sensitive info removed) which I have attached below. This code is not yet complete. Once I clean it up I'll try to publish it as a toolbar. In the meantime...just add your sheet id and sheetname/range.

```
#load the required packages/libraries/etc
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']

# The ID and range of a sample spreadsheet.
SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = 'SHEETID'
SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME = 'DATA_SHEET!Range:'


#adapted from quickstart
def getDataFromTable():
    """Shows basic usage of the Sheets API.
    Prints values from a sample spreadsheet.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server()
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Sheets API
    sheet = service.spreadsheets()
    result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                                range=SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME).execute()
    values = result.get('values', [])
    return values


data = getDataFromTable()
headers = data.pop(0)

#now we can start the qgis-y stuff
vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point", "temp", "memory")
pr = vl.dataProvider()
for attrb in headers: 
  pr.addAttributes([QgsField(attrb, QVariant.String)])

vl.updateFields()

for datum in data:
    print(datum)
    f = QgsFeature()
    f.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(float(datum[12]),float(datum[11]))))
    f.setAttributes(datum)
    pr.addFeature(f)
    vl.updateExtents()
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

Comment: Hello Tyler, I'm intrigued if you had any updates on this?

Comment: Hey Tyler, I'm also curious if you've already published it as a toolbar?

Comment: or as a plugin..

Answer (score 4):

We have been pulling Google Sheets into QGIS via PostgreSQL Foreign Data Wrappers. We then build a materialized view that connects records to geometry (via School Numbers, for example) and use the materialized view as a standard spatial table.

From there we have also published this 'google sheet materialized view' to a web application via node.js and add a button to refresh the map if the google sheet data has been changed. It works really well.

### Method 1: Multicorn FDW and GSheets Extension:

(Note: The gsspreadsheet extension to the multicorn FDW is questionably maintained, and there is the risk that v4 of the GSheets API may break it... we don't know yet, and are planning for the possibility that we might have to implement Method 2 (below) if it does indeed break. )

To connect to a Google Sheet via a PostgreSQL FDW, use the Multicorn FDW:

https://github.com/Kozea/Multicorn

Then install the gspreadsheet_fdw extension for Multicorn:

https://github.com/lincolnturner/gspreadsheet_fdw

In PostgreSQL, create the multicorn FDW:

```
CREATE SERVER multicorn_gspreadsheet
    FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER multicorn
    OPTIONS (wrapper 'gspreadsheet_fdw.GspreadsheetFdw');
```

Then create the FDW table connecting to the Google Sheet using the gspreadsheet extension of multicorn:

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE speced_fdw.centerprogram_current_gsheet (
    column1 integer NULL,
    column2 varchar NULL,
    column3 varchar NULL 
)
SERVER multicorn_gspreadsheet
OPTIONS (keyfile '/usr/pgsql-9.5/share/credential.json', gskey 'example_d33lk2kdislids');
```

You now have a foreign table pointing directly to your Google Sheet, which you can built a materialized view from.

### Method 2: Using FILE_FDW and CSV GSheet Export:

The other option is to use the FILE_FDW right out of PostgreSQL and connect to the CSV export of the GSheet using WGET.

First, create the server:

```
CREATE SERVER fdw_files
    FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER file_fdw
    OPTIONS ()
```

Then create the FDW table:

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE public.test_file_fdw (
    "name" varchar NOT NULL,
    "date" varchar NULL,
    "address" varchar NULL
)
SERVER fdw_files
OPTIONS (program 'wget -q -O - "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/2343randomurlcharacters_r0/export?gid=969976&format=csv"', format 'csv', header 'true');
```

The above options for wget are listed here: https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/HTTP-Options.html

Comment: This sounds really useful and interesting, I'd love to know more  and think it would be a great addition to this answer!

Comment: @GISKid ok cool let me add some more details. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @GISKid sorry for the delay, but posted a few links to the FDW's we're using. Let me know if you need any more info for now...

Answer (score 3):

The most basic option is to export the table as a CSV file and import it in QGIS. You there have the option to *watch the file* for updates.

If exporting CSVs isn't an option, you can use a desktop spreadsheet and connect it to a database, or use a database in the first place. A good example from actual practice can be found in [an older answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/226685/13426).

You should also look at the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/) to see if you can use it in some way.